# Classnames Bind and global classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getelementsbyclassname

Here is a really silly question to which I was unable to find answers.

How can I **concatenate a binded css modules class and a global one**?

I have a component with his own css module and I bind cx to this import:

```
import styles from '../styles/modules/break.module.scss'

let cx = classnames.bind(styles)
```

I need to write something like this:

```
<h1 className={(cx('highlight'), 'shout')}>
  Content
</h1>
```

Where `.highlight` is a class of `break.module.scss` while `shout` is a class of a global css sheet `index.scss`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `shout` class inside `cx`. All classes should be passed inside the `cx` function, since `classnames` library takes all the classes inside the `classnames` function.

```
<h1 className={cx('highlight', 'shout')}>
  Content
</h1>
```